# Setting socket connection inside another thread

Tags: android

I am connecting to socket server with following code:

```
XMPPConnection connection;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig=new ConnectionConfiguration("178.62.84.123", 5222,"localhost");
                connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
                try{
                    connection.connect();
                }catch(XMPPException ex) {
                    setConnection(null);
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
}
private void onPause() {
     try {
          connection.disconnect();
     } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

I am setting `connection` variable inside thread.But when I try to disconnect my app is crashing.

Logcat:

```
02-02 14:16:15.080: E/XMPPConnection(8047): Error in listener while closing connection
02-02 14:16:15.080: E/XMPPConnection(8047): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-02 14:16:15.080: E/XMPPConnection(8047):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
02-02 14:16:15.080: E/XMPPConnection(8047):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-02 14:16:15.080: E/XMPPConnection(8047):     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:365)
02-02 14:16:15.080: E/XMPPConnection(8047):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5Proxy.<init>(Socks5Proxy.java:108)
02-02 14:16:15.080: E/XMPPConnection(8047):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5Proxy.getSocks5Proxy(Socks5Proxy.java:163)
```

Why it is trying disconnect from ui thread ? I am setting `connection` inside another thread.

Ps:I followed this:http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000119

Comment: OnPause is called in the UI thread, so the disconnect is also called on the UI thread. It doesn't quite matter on which thread the object is made.

Comment: What is the best solution for this ?

Comment: You should only try to disconnect if `connection!=null`; And having done that set it to null.

Comment: @greenapps already connection is not null.

Comment: Well, you should at least check, but also call disconnect on a thread.

Comment: Creating new thread on every onpause does it make sense ?

Comment: @Okan: more than calling a network-related method on the main thread.

Comment: The question is more: "does it make sense to close the connection in onPause()?".

Comment: Could it be memory leak or another problems ? I don't know exactly thread logic.

Comment: @greenapps What do you suggest ? Please explain me.I want to learn.

Comment: As i do not know what your code is doing i cannot tell you what to do.

Comment: @greenapps it is a chat app and i am connecting to socket server

Comment: That is not enough info. But in general: if you want to use `connection` again after onPause then it will be uninitialised and unusable so then better close it. As you are creating ALWAYS a new connection in onCreate() you better close the former one.

Comment: Also, when OnPause is called, OnCreate might not recalled when coming back to that activity, see http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/activity_lifecycle.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample the disconnect is called within a thread so it doesn't block the UI waiting for network messages. However, in this sample I do not reconnect and you should implement it for the correct state (OnResume probably).

```
XMPPConnection connection = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig=new ConnectionConfiguration("178.62.84.123", 5222,"localhost");
                connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
                try{
                connection.connect();
            }catch(XMPPException ex) {
                setConnection(null);
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    });
    t.start();
}
private void onPause() {
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
               try {
                    if (connection != null)
                        connection.disconnect();
               } catch (NotConnectedException e) {

               }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure is this a good solution.There will be so many threads ? If user pauses app for 10 times is there will be 10 thread ? I don't know exactly threads.Please inform me :)

Comment: A thread ends when it finished executing its block, so they won't stack.

Comment: Change `XMPPConnection connection;` to `XMPPConnection connection=null;`.

Comment: It is working but i am curious about one thing: connection.send method is sending data to server and no need call inside the thread.why i should call disconnect inside thread ?

Comment: Because disconnect probably sends a disconnect message to the server and waits for a acknowledgement.

Comment: So,I can send data to server from ui thread but can't receive.Right ?

Comment: No, since XMPP uses a tcp-connection all messages will be confirmed. Which can take some time.